# symfony2 form validation: form.errors VS form.fieldname.errors

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms

i have a issue with how the errors are appearing.

below is part from my form builder

```
->add('editions', 'entity', array(
    'multiple' => true, 
    'expanded' => true, 
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Edition', 
    'property' => 'name',
    'constraints' => new Count(array('min' => 1, 'minMessage' => 'Choose at least one edition')),
    )
)
->add('releaseDates', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new ReleaseDateFormType(),
    'allow_add'    => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'constraints' => new Count(array('min' => 1, 'minMessage' => 'Choose at least one release date')),
    )
)
```

The validation is working, but the problem is, that for the first field "editions" the error is "attached" to field itself, i.e.

```
{{ form_errors(form.editions) }}
```

and for the second field error is attached to the form, but not to a field

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

so how its possible assign the error to a field and not to a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add option `'error_bubbling' => false` to releaseDates

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own validator which extends from the count class. Then you use the following function in your validate function (instead of addViolation)

```
$context->addViolationAt('fieldname', 'message', array(), null);

In Symfony 2.1:
$context->addViolationAtSubPath('fieldname', 'message', array(), null);
```

You could make the fieldname a paramerter for reuse:

```
'constraints' => new Count(array('fieldname' => $fieldname, 'min' => 1, 'minMessage' => 'Choose at least one edition'))
```

Comment: as i said, validation is working, its just setting error message on the form, but to field, setting 'error_bubbling' => false helps, thanks to Michael Sivolobov

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
{{ form_errors(form.releaseDates) }}
```